# Parsing Json not displaying all items in it

Tags: json, nsdictionary

I have been trying to make this code work with swift3 latest beta version but got tired of no luck

Can you please someone try tell me how to fix it.  I have 3 items that come back on my response but I can just see one been displayed on my tableview below the code

that is my response

> (
>           {
>           itemaddedby = Rodrigo;
>           itemaddeddate = "2016-08-24 17:37:07";
>           itemdescription = pizza;
>           itemid = 66;
>       },
>           {
>           itemaddedby = "";
>           itemaddeddate = "2016-08-26 22:38:33";
>           itemdescription = "";
>           itemid = 67;
>       },
>           {
>           itemaddedby = rodrigo;
>           itemaddeddate = "2016-08-23 22:45:51";
>           itemdescription = cheese;
>           itemid = 65;
>       } )

```
func GetAllItems(){
        var processedOk = true
        if let url = URL(string: "http://www.goemobile.com/mobile/todo/getitems.php"){
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST";// Compose a query string
            let postString = ""
            request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request as URLRequest){
                data, response, error in

                if error != nil{
                    print("1\(error)")
                }
                else{
                    _ = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                }
                do {


                    if let convertedJsonIntoDict = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSArray {
                        if convertedJsonIntoDict.count > 0{
                            let item =  (convertedJsonIntoDict[0] as! NSDictionary)["itemdescription"] as? String
                            if item != nil{
                                self.TableData.append(item!)
                                DispatchQueue.global().async {
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.table.reloadData()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else{

                                // self.lblError.text = "Something went wrong. Try again"
                            }
                        }
                        else{
                            processedOk=false
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        DispatchQueue.global().async {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }

            }
            task.resume()
            self.table.reloadData()
        }

    }
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Why do you create a string ` _ = NSString(...` for nothing and why do you dispatch first to global and then to main queue? That's both pretty weird. The reason that only one item is displayed is that you are processing only one item (`convertedJsonIntoDict[0]`) rather then iterating through all items. PS: The variable `processedOk` has actually no effect at all because it's local.

Comment: Thanks vadian, can you please show me how to iterate with all items to get the values please. I am stuck and as you can see, I am new to Swift

Comment: Iterating through a dictionary is absolutely basic Swift programming. You'll need to learn it. I'm quite sure Apple's Swift book has examples.

Comment: I understand that might be a basic Swift programming for you. If I am asking is because I looked many times but unfortunately I couldn't figure it out. That is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, unfortunately not tested

```
func getAllItems(){ // function names are supposed to start with a lowercase letter
  if let url = URL(string: "http://www.goemobile.com/mobile/todo/getitems.php"){
    var request = URLRequest(url:url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST";// Compose a query string
    let postString = ""
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:request) { data, response, error in

      if error != nil{
        print("1\(error)")
        return
      }
      do {
        if let convertedJson = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [[String:Any]] {
          for item in convertedJson {
            if let description =  item["itemdescription"] as? String {
              self.TableData.append(description)
            }
          }
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.table.reloadData()
          }
        }
      }
      catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
      }
    }
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

The code uses Swift native collection types rather than Foundation `NSArray` / `NSDictionary`. It makes things a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Vadian, That worked. I really appreciate your help